# simple database text file in c++

Tags: c++, database, text

i want to make a database of animals that save the data after i close the program. So i thought it should be saved in a text file.

1) Is there an already made c++ function for that?

2) in case not, how can we solve the problem?

Until now, i have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Animal {
  public: 
    std::string name, color1, color2, race, notes;
    int age;
};

void writeInTheDatabase(Animal const& ani);
int readAgeFromTheDataBase(Animal const& ani);

int main() {

    Animal cat1;
    cat1.name = "silvester";
    cat1.color1 = "black";
    cat1.color2 = "white";
    cat1.age = 4;

    Animal dog1;
    dog1.name = "Arnold";
    dog1.color1 = "brown";
    dog1.color2 = "black";
    dog1.age = 3;

    writeInTheDatabase(dog1);
    std::cout << "the age is: " << readAgeFromTheDataBase(dog1) << std::endl;
}

void writeInTheDatabaseTextFile(Animal const& ani) {
    // this function  should put all the info in a text file   
}

int readAgeFromTheDataBase(Animal const& ani) {
    int age;
    // this function should return the age of an animal given
    return age;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Mureinik AFAICT he asks "whether there is already a predefined function". To OP: see http://en.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: `Animals` is misleading since it appears to contain precisely one animal at a time. Also it should probably be "species" rather than "race".

Comment: If it's not for learning C++ only: consider SQLite.

Comment: i needed it for c++

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `std::fstream` to read/write from file. Or maybe you want "c++ serialization", or an actual database.

Comment: Use Boosts' property trees. Easiest solution.

Comment: If you want to make a text file database efficient, you should make each database record (i.e. text line) the same space.  This allows you to calculate the read position without having to search for and count newlines.

Comment: You could also use CSV format for your text file.  Not as efficient as fixed length records.

Comment: You may want to look into XML and get a library for reading and writing XML format files.

Answer (score 0):

There can’t be anything premade for a class that *you* defined.

There are multiple solutions for writing standard data types, as text or binary, in a file (like cout, fprintf, fwrite, etc.), but you need to code a method for your class that handles all it pieces, in the format and sequence you want it.